# CSS fixed positioning issue in Firefox

Tags: html, css, thickbox

I have a modal "div" which appears as a popup over the main content window. Now this modal div uses fixed positioning (actually it is a thickbox div)

The content for this modal div exceeds the available browser height. So the issue is that in Firefox, I am unable to access the content at the bottom of this modal div. The scrollbar is displayed, but it does not scroll through the modal div. It scrolls through the main page. This does not happen in IE (only in Firefox)

How do I fix the issue?

Comment: Please provide some code!

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing any code, my first guess would be to:

1) set overflow-y:auto; css property to the overlay div

2) set a height on the overlay div